# how to install mysqlconnecter java correctly?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, connector

after surfing the web I realized that I should set the class path the path File of the connecter jar file in system environment variables I did so and in commandline by entering this command I have this:

```
C:\Users\User>echo %classpath%
D:\classpath\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar
```

but when I wrote a java program to show me the class path:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
```

it shows me this one:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\build\classes;C:\Users\User\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication3\src
```

I want to connect to a database how should I install my connector?

Comment: Are you using any IDE  for Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JDBC driver does not need any "installation".

You should *not* set the system wide `CLASSPATH` environment variable, that only leads to confusion.

When starting your program, simply provide the location of the file to the Java command:

```
java -cp myapp.jar;D:\classpath\mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar MyMain
```

To use it inside your NetBeans project, add the jar file in the "Libraries" section of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Just add **D:\classpath** to the CLASSPTH using set command (`set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;D:\classpath;`) on the command prompt or by defining a CLASSPATH environment variable using UI.