# Class Not Found Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver?

Tags: java, jdbc, driver, mysql-connector

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found with mysql connector in buildpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920265/com-mysql-jdbc-driver-not-found-with-mysql-connector-in-buildpath)

I'm working on connecting MySQL database to a Java program. When I run my program I am getting this error

> Class Not Found Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

for this line

> try{
>         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

So, what's the problem? I'm placing the connector in the project's file.. Is the correct or should it be in another location?

OS Windows XP, Eclipse 4.0, mysql connector 5.1.22

Comment: Did you include it in the classpath?

Comment: @Nambari project file is in D:/

Comment: @user1929226 *Anywhere* in the CLASSPATH. The question doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAR file need to add to project class path.

```
First Right click on you Eclipse Project,  Project --> Build Path --> Configure Build Path. Under Libraries tab, click Add Jars or "Add External JARs".
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need that line of code, any time in the last five years or so. Just delete it,

Answer (score 0):

The jar file should be in your classpath. If you have created the project through an IDE, make sure you add the jar in your build path.

Comment: how can I jar the connector?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the connector jar file in your project's build path. In eclipse project properties dialog, go to "Java Build Path" and add the jar file in "Libraries" tab

Answer (score 0):

the jar should be included in your classpath. In your IDE, configure your build path and add the required jar in your libraries section.