# Class not found java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I wanted to print the contents in a database but whenever  I run this program I got this error saying that

```
Class not found java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
SQL exception occuredjava.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase
```

I have installed MySQL from this link http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/ its a 248mb file and installed completely. I can access my database within MySQL but can't able to access from netbeans. I separately downloaded the mysql-connector-java-5.1.4.jar and set the CLASSPATH but now also I got this error.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class jdbcResultSet {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      }
      catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
         System.out.println("Class not found "+ e);
      }
      try {  
         Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection
         ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase","root",
         "root");
         Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
         ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery
         ("SELECT * FROM employee");
         System.out.println("id  name    job");
         while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            String job = rs.getString("job");
            System.out.println(id+"   "+name+"    "+job);
         }
      }
      catch(SQLException e){
         System.out.println("SQL exception occured" + e);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: How did u set the classpath of connector jar? and how are you executing your program?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098404/class-not-found-exception-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driv

Same problem it seems

Comment: I downloaded the mysql-connector-java-5.1.4.jar file and placed in "C:\Program Files\MySQL\Java Connector" directory and edit System Environment Variable from control panel then set CLASSPATH as C:\Program Files\MySQL\Java Connector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CLASSPATH environment variable is only used by the `java.exe` command and even then only when used without any of the -cp, -classpath, -jar arguments. It is ignored by IDEs.

So if you are running the application from your IDE place the mysql-connector.jar in your IDE's classpath

Answer (score 1):

First Check can you import import    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;

if it say com.microsft can not be resolved to a  type that means u have to add your jar files to **java build path** and after that to **deployment path** from project properties.

---

**java build path**

- Right click on project=>**Properties**=>**Java Build Path**=>
  **Libraries**s=>**ADD    External Jar file**

---

**deployment path**

- Right click on project=>**Properties**=>**Deployment Assembly**=>
  **ADD**s=>**Java Build Path Entries**==> **mssql_jdbc**

Answer (score 0):

> I downloaded the mysql-connector-java-5.1.4.jar file and placed in "C:\Program Files\MySQL\Java Connector" directory and edit System Environment Variable from control panel then set CLASSPATH as C:\Program Files\MySQL\Java Connector

Add the jar file, not the directory that the jar file is in.

Instead of,

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Java Connector
```

the CLASSPATH should include,

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\Java Connector\mysql-connector-java-5.1.4.jar
```