# MySQL JDBC driver is not found in Windows 10

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, windows-10

I installed `jdk 1.8 (64 bit)` on Windows 10. I also installed `MySQL workbench 6.3`.

When I connect my Java application with a MySQL database, I am getting:

```
java.lang.Classnotfound exception: com.sql.jdbc.driver.
```

To get rid of this problem I already copied the MySQL java connector .jar file in
`C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_51\lib\ext` folder.

Also I set the `PATH` in system variables by going into advanced environment settings panel.

Still getting same message when running my Java application.

Comment: Did you [Google](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=g91rVtnuFqTv8wec_JiADg&gws_rd=ssl#q=java.lang.classnotfoundexception+com.mysql.jdbc.driver) for this?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484764/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver-in-eclipse

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591505/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-mysql-jdbc-driver

Comment: It is `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`; so **my**sql, not sql. And you should not put things in `lib\ext`; it is going to be removed in Java 9 anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found with mysql connector in buildpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920265/com-mysql-jdbc-driver-not-found-with-mysql-connector-in-buildpath)

Comment: Have a look at: [another StackOverFlow-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12920265/com-mysql-jdbc-driver-not-found-with-mysql-connector-in-buildpath)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check following things:
1. Unzip driver jar file and check "com.sql.jdbc.Driver" is available?
2. If not then you can download latest jar file from mysql web page. 
3. In side "com.mysql.jdbc" package "Driver" class is there, so you can use  "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" driver.
4. If you run your application on cmd or linux terminal then set classpath for complie and run your application.
5. If you use any IDE then update your application build path with driver jar.